# How to add user to LDAP group using Python?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am using [Python-LDAP](https://www.python-ldap.org) to interact with Active Directory, and struggling to find what code I need to write to add a user into a security group.

I have already written the code to search for the DN of the user and group, I am just unsure as to what function I need to use to add the user in. I came across this:

LDAPObject.add_s(dn, modlist)

So I have the DN already, but when I've searched modlist I get this:

ldap.modlist.addModlist(entry[, ignore_attr_types=[]])

I'm not sure if I need modifyModlist or addModlist, and am unsure of the values I need to send to it.

I thought I would just be able to send the user and group DN to a function and it would add the user to the group... guess it isn't that simple?

Answer (score 6):

Module [ldap.modlist](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-modlist.html) just contains convenience functions for generating lists of modifications. You have to call method [LDAPObject.modify_s()](https://python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.modify_s) to actually modify the group entry.

Let's assume you have the user entry's DN in variable *user_dn* and *group_dn* is the DN of the group entry and with *ldap_conn* being your LDAPObject instance.

Then you would simply use:

```
ldap_conn.modify_s(
    group_dn,
    [
        (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user_dn]),
    ],
)
```

Of course you can also remove users and add other users in one modify operation:

```
ldap_conn.modify_s(
    group_dn,
    [
        (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user1_dn, user2_dn]),
        (ldap.MOD_DELETE, 'member', [user3_dn, user4_dn]),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting TypeError *Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): expected a tuple* when I tried to apply the anwser from Michael Ströder. To fix that err, wrap modlist content to the tuple:

```
ldap_conn.modify_s(
    group_dn,
    [
        (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user_dn],)
    ],
)
```

also, make sure user_dn is a bytestring.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `ldap.OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: {'info': u"attribute 'member' not allowed", 'desc': u'Object class violation'}`

In our environment each group member (UID) was listed as a `memberUid` attribute in the groups, hence this worked for us:

```
ldap_conn.modify_s(
    group_dn,
    [
        (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'memberUid', [<uid>],)
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import ldap

conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
ldap_base = 'dc=example,dc=local'
```

Change your DC
Group dn should be a string

```py
group_dn = 'CN=Group Policy Creator Owners,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
user_dn =  b'CN=test1,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local'
```

Note we haven't used modlist which is used for key attribute pairs

```py
conn.modify_s(
  group_dn, [
    (ldap.MOD_ADD, 'member', [user_dn],)],
)
```